# Sessions and the encryption key in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I have seen similar to this question asked and answered and I have tried to follow the instructions as per the codeigniter site but I am stuck. I get the message when trying to use sessions

> In order to use the Session class you are required to set an
>   encryption key in your config file.

I have set this in the config file as requested eg:

`$config['encryption_key'] = 'encryption_key4454545';`

and whether I use autoload or manual methods the message keeps coming back. I have tried to view the contents of the encryption key `[$this->config->item('encryption_key')]` but it is empty, whereas other values from the config file are displayed.

So it seems CI is ignoring my encryption key config section.

Has anyone experienced this or supply any ideas as to what is happening.

Comment: whether I use autoload or manual methods the message keeps coming back. ??? what is that message ????

Comment: saurabh2836, The message is "In order to use the Session class you are required to set an encryption key in your config file." Which I have done.

Comment: Hi Sir, have yo solved this problem? I have exactly the same problem as you do.

Answer (score 2):

Try to paste key from this generator:

[generator](http://randomkeygen.com/)

Key from this website will be working.

Comment: Hi Cam Cam I have tried this also but still to no avail. What I have noticed, just for testing, is that if I change the base_url value and save that it still displays the old base_url value. So suggesting that CI is using a cached version and not the updated version